# HTML title attribute in Rails displaying only first word

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hover

Got a weird little problem.

I want to create the text hover on an item to display that item's "description," which is an attribute of that item's model. So I basically did this in my view:

```
<div title=<%= item.description %> ><%= item.name %></div>
```

The weird thing is, while all the model calls are working correctly (item.name and item.description are calling up the right things), only the first word of item.description is showing up when I hover. In other words, if item.description is "This is a super cool item!", when I hover over that div with item.name, the hover just says "This".

This may have something to do with the :description attribute, which is currently of type text, (which I thought was for long strings, like my descriptions). But maybe not.

Any idea why this might be happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: This is because you need to have "quotes" around a multiword title. eg. `<div title="This is a super cool item!">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to add quoting to the HTML in the view. If you view source on the generated HTML, I'm willing to bet it looks like this:

```
<div title=This is a super cool item! >
```

The browser will interpret that as the `div` having a `title` with the value `This`, and then attributes named `is`, `a`, `super`, `cool`, and `item!`.

If you change your view to this:

```
<div title="<%= item.description %>" >
```

Then your generated HTML should look like this:

```
<div title="This is a super cool item!" >
```

Answer (score 7):

Insert double qutoes for title in the div tag

```
<div title="<%= item.description %>" ><%= item.name %></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
<div title=<%= item.description %> ><%= item.name %></div>
```

to this:

```
<div title="<%= item.description %>" ><%= item.name %></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, everybody! Worked like a charm.