# loading JSON data in title of table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm having a problem to load my JSON data in the title of my table. In my function loadJSON I'm loading an object's comment in like this:

```html
<tr title="this['achievementlist'][i].comment"></tr>
```

resulting in:
[link of picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo437.png)

when I remove the ". the comment is loaded, but only the first word. 
after reading: [HTML title attribute in Rails displaying only first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055584/html-title-attribute-in-rails-displaying-only-first-word)
I added the " back in. Logically this again resulted in [link of picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo437.png).

how could I load in the JSON comment of object 'achievementlist' as an title?

The JSON data:

```html
{
"gijs":[
    {
      "name": "gijs",
      "walletpoints": "5",
      "totalpoints": "5",
      "achievementlist":[
      {
        "achievementname": "een comaan",
        "points": "50",
        "comment": "werkt voor geen meter en ziet er niet uit"
      },
      {
        "achievementname": "meer dan 5 huisdieren",
        "points": "40",
        "comment": "allemaal muizen in de kelder"
      }
}
```

all of my html code:

```html
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="achievements"></td>
                            <script>
                                $.getJSON("../json/package.json", function (data)
                                {
                                    $.each(data.gijs, function ()
                                    {
                                        for (var i=0; i<this['achievementlist'].length; i++)
                                        {
                                            $(".achievements").append("<tr title="+"this['achievementlist'][i].comment" +" class='tablerow'><td class='JSONDATA'><div class='JSONName'>" + this['achievementlist'][i].achievementname + "</div><div class='JSONPoints'>Points:   " + "<strong>"+this['achievementlist'][i].points+"</strong>" + "</div></td></tr>");
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to load the actual comment into the title attribute?

Comment: Yes, one comment in my question is: "werkt voor geen meter en ziet er niet uit" if I hover over the table data i want to read: "werkt voor geen meter en ziet er niet uit".

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = {
"gijs":[
    {
      "name": "gijs",
      "walletpoints": "5",
      "totalpoints": "5",
      "achievementlist":[
      {
        "achievementname": "een comaan",
        "points": "50",
        "comment": "werkt voor geen meter en ziet er niet uit"
      },
      {
        "achievementname": "meer dan 5 huisdieren",
        "points": "40",
        "comment": "allemaal muizen in de kelder"
      }]
}]
}

$.each(data.gijs, function (){
for (var i=0; i<this['achievementlist'].length; i++){
$(".achievements").append('<tr title="'+this['achievementlist'][i].comment+'" class="tablerow"><td class="JSONDATA"><div class="JSONName">'+ this['achievementlist'][i].achievementname + '</div><div class="JSONPoints">Points <strong>'+this['achievementlist'][i].points+'</strong></div></td></tr>');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="achievements"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```